# Powershell Array - If 2 Arrays contain same combination of hashes

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable, contains

Sadly I don't know the exact word for what my problem is, but I try to explain it and I'd be happy if someone could tell me what I should be looking for :)

I have two arrays

Array 1  with Name, Surname, and Array 2 with Name, Surname aswell.

Of course, Surnames and Names are NOT unique, but the combination of them is unique.

So now I'd need to check if the Combination of Array 1 IS existing in Array 2, if not do something...

Now my problem is that i know -contains but I don't know how to use that on multiple hashes (Contains Surname or Name only is not useful, it has to be and)

i tried the following

```
if ( $oldList -notcontains $newPerson.Name -and $newPerson.Surname) {....}
```

But it neither worked nor I expected it to work or I did another mistake?!

Could anybody give me some advice? Thanks in advance

PS. It is not Surname/Name in my case, but I for understanding Surname/Name is easier!

**Update**

The Hashtables (or Arrays?!) look with an Write-Host like this:

```
@{Name=Peter; Surname=Fox}.... and so on
```

**Update 2 - Solution**

Hey Guys, just for every future reader who maybe doesn't find out by himself...

It's an Compare-Object $arr1 $arr2 - and it outputs every diffenence by either => odr =<

:) Therefore question is answered (by myself :P)

Comment: If I understand you right, you have *objects* in both arrays, that each have `Name` and `Surname` properties? Or is it an array of arrays where each element is a (Name, Surname) tuple?

Comment: I think those are all Objects in an Array, but to be honest I dont know - I updated the question I hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Compare-Object $arr1 $arr2
```

delivers the solution I was looking for. It shows differences by => and <= and therefore you can evaluate if it is containd in arr2 or not.